# Loop structure for adding up coordinates in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, geolocation, coordinates

I have an array with coordinates in and want to add them up to determine a total distance (not just from point A to point B).

My array is structured as latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2 and so on.

I have to code to actually work out the distance (shown below), but don't know how to do the loop needed to get the coordinates.

```
 function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
   var R = 6371;
   var a = 
      0.5 - Math.cos((lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180)/2 + 
      Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) * 
      (1 - Math.cos((lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180))/2;

   return R * 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
 }
```

How should the loop be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Would [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) be of any use to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways, I would do it like this:

```
int sum(int[] array) {
 int sum = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
  sum += distance(array[i], array[i+1], array[i+2], array[i+3]);
  i +=4;
 }
 return sum;
}
```